# MVC Cache Based on Variables in Session and Custom Security Logic

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, caching

I have an application that shows many charts and tables using JQuery. Some of these charts are based on variables that are saved in the session (E.g. user added a value in another page and in the next page I am generating a chart, so the user request doesn't send any parameters)

I was looking around on the net and most of the solutions are based on

```
 [OutputCache(Duration=60, VaryByParam="someParm")]
```

The problem is most of my request don't send parameters, they just use values that are in the session.

Is there any way to enable cache for these kinds of requests?

**Edit:** We have a complex security requirement that we couldn't use the default authorization attribute of MVC. We had to write logics based on the current user + the parameters sent to the action, so a method inside the action decides either to go ahead with the request or returns nothing. This makes caching very difficult because at the time OutputCache is executed we just have parameters, but identity object in the context is empty. As a result, if a user with admin privilege send a request for a and b and after him someone with minimum privilege send request for a and b, the second person will see the result because the action didn't run, but the value from the cache is used!

To solve this problem I used the getvarybyCustome. All this function does is to return user's group name which helps to create a more complex key. The person with minimum privilege in the last example will have different cache key (a,b,group_less) than the admin's request cache key (a,b,group_admin). However, getting's group name for each request is expensive as well, so I use Cache object to cache user's group, so at the beginning of the session the user's group is queried from AD and saved to cache, so  for his/her later requests, his group name is retrieved from cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something you can't achieve by `VaryByParam` then you can try `VaryByCustom`. See an example [here](http://visitmix.com/writings/using-varybycustom-with-outputcache-in-asp-net-mvc-to-support-caching-for-logged-in-users)

Comment: The problem is when GetVaryByCustomString is called the session object is null :(

Answer (score 1):

You could make a redirect of this request and send it to a new controller method sending the session parameters, by this way in a future implementation may be you use query string parameters instead of session and your code will work too.

You could make a method for conversion of this session parameters on a base class of all your controllers, to write the conversion once.